# What can cause CRAN to show package errors from another package?

Tags: r, package, cran

I've just pushed a new version of package `userfriendlyscience` (version 0.5-0) to CRAN. The [`CHECK` results for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_userfriendlyscience.html) show errors. Viewing these shows that they seem to be caused by another package, specifically `mgcv`, or perhaps another package in the dependency tree desiring to use previously `export`ed functions from this package.

I installed the newest `R-devel` and ran `RCMD CHECK --as-cran` again, but this still completes without any errors etc. As far as I can see, the package I submitted 'works'.

So I assume that indeed, the errors shows by CRAN reside in other packages. But, how can that be? Shouldn't CRAN block submission of packages with such errors, in other words, shouldn't it be impossible for a package that causes errors to exist on CRAN?

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can start figuring out what exactly goes wrong, so that I can fix it (if it turns out to be this package after all) or notify the authors of this is caused by another package?

*[note: the previous version did cause an error, which has been resolved in 0.5-0]*

*[For anybody who want to verify the successful installation in Windows: instructions for installing the uploaded source version as well as the compiled windows version [are here](http://userfriendlyscience.com)]*

Comment: `could not find function "scaleReliability"` in one of your unit tests does not indicate an error in another package. Whatever gave you that idea? If you look closely where version 0.4-1 fails it is in your tests. Version 0.5-0 apparently can't be installed on Windows.

Comment: No, that's true - and that error has been solved in 0.5-0. I meant that version - sorry, I should have been more explicit. I'll edit the question to address this ambiguity.

Comment: OK. Then have you installed your package successfully on a Windows OS?

Comment: Yes, it installs successfully. I guess that makes sense as `R CMD CHECK` doesn't find any errors, no?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully install from source on Win10. But I get an error regarding a cyclic namespace dependency during the process. Maybe CRAN is more strict there and stops on error. Btw., why do you think that the problem is "caused by another package"? I seriously doubt that. (Although I also wouldn't be terribly surprised if your package's huge dependency tree caused issues. I had to install a sh*tload of packages.)

Comment: Well, when I look at [https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-windows-ix86+x86_64/userfriendlyscience-00install.html](the error), a list of functions from [mgcv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) is shown. For the first list, the error itself isn't shown (truncated), and the second list shows functions that are not exported (but that `userfriendlyscience` doesn't use).

You're right re: all the packages `userfriendlyscience` imports; it's mainly a 'wrapper package' that makes some functionality more accessible to people who are new to R.

Comment: I have no idea what happens there and how that could be a Windows specific problem. mgcv is probably imported indirectly by one of your dependencies. However, `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` is not a good practice. Try being more specific in your exports and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: You could try if you can reproduce the problem on win-builder.r-project.org.

Comment: That was a good tip - I wasn't aware of that server. I did this, and all tests run without problems. The `RCMD CHECK` output is the same as what I get locally, and the package installs without problems, giving the same namespace dependency error (I thought that was caused by package A importing the namespace of package B when package B also imports the namespace of package A, e.g. when they import unrelated functions from each other). So - thanks for the help troubleshooting, but the situation remains confusing I'm afraid :-/

Comment: I'd ask at [the mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel). If that fails you could ask the CRAN maintainers directly.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, thanks. Will keep this open until I have an answer and will then add it here (to "share knowledge, Q&A style" :-)). Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127701/discussion-between-matherion-and-roland).

Answer (score 1):

(answering myself this in case others run into this)

This issue resolved itself. After a while, CRAN no longer indicated the same error.

On the basis of this and experiences with another upload, I currently suspect that CRAN isn't 'ready' at any given point; rather, it continually builds packages. Therefore, it's possible that a package happens to run into some errors in a window where one package has already been updated, but a package depending on that package not yet. The errors resulting from the incompatibility then show up for your package.

The solution, assuming this interpretation is accurate, would then be to wait a few days to see whether the situation resolves itself. If not, I'd suggest trying to contact the maintainer of the package that throws the error to see whether they maybe know what's happening.